# what is the alternate source path for google markerclusterer.js library?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

in  my project I am including this library like this:

```
<script src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
```

however the src path seems to be broken since yesterday hence it is not rendering the JS thus I am unable to show clusters on the map.

I do have the local copy for this JS, I can set src path to refer to my local copy instead of above *../svnt/runk/..* path.

What I am searching is there any alternative path for this library? May be it is hosted on CDN.

So far, I think, above is *only* the place where it is hosted:

Ref: https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/checkout

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As [Google moved the source over to GitHub](http://google-opensource.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/farewell-to-google-code.html) a while back, the new [GitHub version](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer) can be accessed from [RawGit](https://rawgit.com/) by using the following script url:

```
https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/src/markerclusterer.js
```

You'll also need to specify the imagePath option when instantiating your MarkerClusterer to access the images from GitHub:

```
var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, { 
    imagePath: 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/images/m' 
});
```

The following earlier SO post contains more detail regarding the imagePath reference to the cluster images:

[Google maps not working in https://](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37093736/1301937)

Whilst the above urls (with the cdn prefixes) have [no traffic limits or throttling and the files are served via a super fast global CDN](https://rawgit.com/), please bear in mind that [RawGit is a free hosting service and offers no uptime or support guarantees](https://github.com/rgrove/rawgit/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#i-need-guaranteed-100-uptime-should-i-use-cdnrawgitcom).

This is covered in more detail in the following SO answer:

[Link and execute external JavaScript file hosted on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18049842/1301937)

**This post also covers that, if you're linking to files on GitHub, in production you should consider targeting a specific release tag to ensure you're getting a specific release version of the script.**

**However, as the custodians of the js-marker-clusterer repository have yet to create any releases, this isn't currently possible.**

**As a result, you should seriously consider downloading and including the library and its resources directly in your project for production purposes.**

Comment: It's bad practise to reference libraries in your code from git/svn repositories. They can be changed/removed/moved any time. That's why people experienced issues with it yesterday. You should download them and include in your project or reference them from some CDN.

Comment: compiled version is removed now

Answer (score 8):

Here I have links for you :

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-marker-clusterer/1.0.0/markerclusterer.js
```

Markercluster Compiled

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-marker-clusterer/1.0.0/markerclusterer_compiled.js
```

Comment: Now I am able to load js file, however there one issue related to it, the js file has default image path set to:  'http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/' +
    'images/m';   to change this default path either I will have to edit that file, which is not possible if I use CDN as src path or I will have to figure a way to override this default through its options if available. Thanks for the CDN link

Comment: Check [THIS LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7835771/4018240), it will be helpful for you...

Comment: @Rahul I've added an additional answer covering using the GitHub hosted version (including the images) which may be useful for you

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer

with great examples in examples folder and good README. However you need to modify one line of code in each of the examples/*.html files to include your API key:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY">
</script>
```

so that each of the three examples work correctly.